# Where to initialize jquery for laravel

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, laravel-blade, fancytree

I am trying to add the drag and drop functionality to my fancy tree. However, there seem to be an issue with where i am initializing the jquery library resulting in error messages indicating that the jquery function i am trying to use is not available etc.

Specific error message = app.js:24 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).perfectScrollbar is not a function TypeError: $(...).perfectScrollbar is not a function

If i were to directly initialize a perfect scroll bar, it will continue reflecting other libraries are not a function etc

Simplistic overview of code (Edited to show that master blade is already requiring jquery once)

--Master Blade--

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}" @if (config('voyager.multilingual.rtl')) dir="rtl" @endif>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('page_title', setting('admin.title') . " - " . setting('admin.description'))</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ voyager_asset('images/logo-icon.png') }}" type="image/x-icon">

    <!-- App CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ voyager_asset('css/app.css') }}">

    <!-- fancy tree jquery/css-->
    @yield('css')


    @if(config('voyager.multilingual.rtl'))
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.4.0/css/bootstrap-rtl.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ voyager_asset('css/rtl.css') }}">
    @endif

    <!-- Few Dynamic Styles -->
    <style type="text/css">
        .voyager .side-menu .navbar-header {
            background:#FFFFFF;
            border-color:#FFFFFF;
            {{--background:{{ config('voyager.primary_color','#22A7F0') }};--}}
            {{--border-color:{{ config('voyager.primary_color','#22A7F0') }};--}}
        }
        .widget .btn-primary{
            border-color:{{ config('voyager.primary_color','#22A7F0') }};
        }
        .widget .btn-primary:focus, .widget .btn-primary:hover, .widget .btn-primary:active, .widget .btn-primary.active, .widget .btn-primary:active:focus{
            background:{{ config('voyager.primary_color','#22A7F0') }};
        }
        .voyager .breadcrumb a{
            color:{{ config('voyager.primary_color','#22A7F0') }};
        }
        .app-container .side-menu .panel.widget h5 {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            width: 180px;
            text-align: left;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity .3s ease;
            margin-top: 17px;
            left: 68px;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 29px;
        }
        .app-container .side-menu .panel.widget h6 {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 15px;
            width: 180px;
            text-align: left;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity .3s ease;
            margin-top: 17px;
            left: 68px;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 29px;
        }
        .app-container.expanded .panel.widget h5 {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .app-container.expanded .panel.widget h6 {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .app-container .side-menu:hover .panel.widget h5 {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .app-container .side-menu:hover .panel.widget h6 {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>

    @if(!empty(config('voyager.additional_css')))<!-- Additional CSS -->
        @foreach(config('voyager.additional_css') as $css)<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset($css) }}">@endforeach
    @endif

    @yield('head')
</head>

<body class="voyager @if(isset($dataType) && isset($dataType->slug)){{ $dataType->slug }}@endif">

<div id="voyager-loader">
    <?php $admin_loader_img = Voyager::setting('admin.loader', ''); ?>
    @if($admin_loader_img == '')
        <img src="{{ voyager_asset('images/logo-icon.png') }}" alt="Voyager Loader">
    @else
        <img src="{{ Voyager::image($admin_loader_img) }}" alt="Voyager Loader">
    @endif
</div>

<?php
if (starts_with(Auth::user()->avatar, 'http://') || starts_with(Auth::user()->avatar, 'https://')) {
    $user_avatar = Auth::user()->avatar;
} else {
    $user_avatar = Voyager::image(Auth::user()->avatar);
}
?>

<div class="app-container">
    <div class="fadetoblack visible-xs"></div>
    <div class="row content-container">
        @include('voyager::dashboard.navbar')
        @include('voyager::dashboard.sidebar')
        <script>
            (function(){
                    var appContainer = document.querySelector('.app-container'),
                        sidebar = appContainer.querySelector('.side-menu'),
                        navbar = appContainer.querySelector('nav.navbar.navbar-top'),
                        loader = document.getElementById('voyager-loader'),
                        hamburgerMenu = document.querySelector('.hamburger'),
                        sidebarTransition = sidebar.style.transition,
                        navbarTransition = navbar.style.transition,
                        containerTransition = appContainer.style.transition;

                    sidebar.style.WebkitTransition = sidebar.style.MozTransition = sidebar.style.transition =
                    appContainer.style.WebkitTransition = appContainer.style.MozTransition = appContainer.style.transition =
                    navbar.style.WebkitTransition = navbar.style.MozTransition = navbar.style.transition = 'none';

                    if (window.localStorage && window.localStorage['voyager.stickySidebar'] == 'true') {
                        appContainer.className += ' expanded no-animation';
                        loader.style.left = (sidebar.clientWidth/2)+'px';
                        hamburgerMenu.className += ' is-active no-animation';
                    }

                   navbar.style.WebkitTransition = navbar.style.MozTransition = navbar.style.transition = navbarTransition;
                   sidebar.style.WebkitTransition = sidebar.style.MozTransition = sidebar.style.transition = sidebarTransition;
                   appContainer.style.WebkitTransition = appContainer.style.MozTransition = appContainer.style.transition = containerTransition;
            })();
        </script>
        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="side-body padding-top">
                @yield('page_header')
                <div id="voyager-notifications"></div>
                @yield('content')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@include('voyager::partials.app-footer')

<!-- Javascript Libs -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ voyager_asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ voyager_asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> -->


<script>
    @if(Session::has('alerts'))
        let alerts = {!! json_encode(Session::get('alerts')) !!};
        helpers.displayAlerts(alerts, toastr);
    @endif

    @if(Session::has('message'))

    // TODO: change Controllers to use AlertsMessages trait... then remove this
    var alertType = {!! json_encode(Session::get('alert-type', 'info')) !!};
    var alertMessage = {!! json_encode(Session::get('message')) !!};
    var alerter = toastr[alertType];

    if (alerter) {
        alerter(alertMessage);
    } else {
        toastr.error("toastr alert-type " + alertType + " is unknown");
    }

    @endif
</script>

@yield('javascript')
<!-- Javascript Libs -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ voyager_asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> -->


@if(!empty(config('voyager.additional_js')))<!-- Additional Javascript -->
    @foreach(config('voyager.additional_js') as $js)<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset($js) }}"></script>@endforeach
@endif

</body>
</html>
```

--Fancy Tree Blade --

```
Extends Master Blade
@section('content')
--fancy tree code--
@stop
@section('javascript)
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/src/jquery-ui-dependencies/jquery.fancytree.ui-deps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/src/jquery.fancytree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/src/jquery.fancytree.dnd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/src/jquery.fancytree.edit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        // using default options
        $("#tree").fancytree({
            extensions: ["dnd"],
            checkbox: false,
            icon: false,
            generateIds: true,
            dnd: {
                autoExpandMS: 400,
                focusOnClick: true,
                preventVoidMoves: true, // Prevent dropping nodes 'before self', etc.
                preventRecursiveMoves: true, // Prevent dropping nodes on own descendants
                dragStart: function(node, data) {
                /** This function MUST be defined to enable dragging for the tree.
                 *  Return false to cancel dragging of node.
                 */
                return true;
                },
                dragEnter: function(node, data) {
                /** data.otherNode may be null for non-fancytree droppables.
                 *  Return false to disallow dropping on node. In this case
                 *  dragOver and dragLeave are not called.
                 *  Return 'over', 'before, or 'after' to force a hitMode.
                 *  Return ['before', 'after'] to restrict available hitModes.
                 *  Any other return value will calc the hitMode from the cursor position.
                 */
                // Prevent dropping a parent below another parent (only sort
                // nodes under the same parent)
        /*           if(node.parent !== data.otherNode.parent){
                    return false;
                }
                // Don't allow dropping *over* a node (would create a child)
                return ["before", "after"];
        */
                return true;
                },
                dragDrop: function(node, data) {
                /** This function MUST be defined to enable dropping of items on
                 *  the tree.
                 */
                data.otherNode.moveTo(node, data.hitMode);
                }
            },
}
```

Comment: My guess is you have more script tags higher up the page that aren't shown....and are loading jQuery.js twice

Comment: yes i do have another javascript tag requiring jquery before the javascript section in the fancy tree file is yielded.

How would you suggest i go about fixing this?

Comment: bring this `<!-- Javascript Libs -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ voyager_asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>` just before `</body>
</html>`in master blade and try

Comment: it returns an error where jquery.js:3850 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).fancytree is not a function.

Comment: I have brought the `js` file in at the bottom and also `@stop` the javascript section in `Fancy Tree Blade` try this

Comment: do you mean to move <!-- Javascript Libs --> <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ voyager_asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> to the fancy tree blade javascript section? i tried that it still doesnt recognize fancy tree as a function

Comment: yeild your `@yield('javascript')` ritght after `@include('voyager::partials.app-footer')` and check `@include('voyager::partials.app-footer')` and look for any kind of js file

Comment: tried doing that as well but to not avail

Comment: Only load jQuery.js once. The second is wiping out the first and any plugin methods you registered before the second one loads

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time getting this error

> TypeError: $(…).perfectScrollbar is not a function

Is because of the wrong Order of scripts and sometimes it is because of jQuery enabled version. in the master.blade, page bring the `@yield('javascript')` right after calling `@include('voyager::partials.app-footer')` and make sure there isn't any js file in `@include('voyager::partials.app-footer')` if there it will cause the same error again so take out the js file and import it in your master.blade file.

Try this

I am trying to add the drag and drop functionality to my fancy tree. However, there seem to be an issue with where i am initializing the jquery library resulting in error messages indicating that the jquery function i am trying to use is not available etc.

Specific error message = app.js:24 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).perfectScrollbar is not a function TypeError: $(...).perfectScrollbar is not a function

If i were to directly initialize a perfect scroll bar, it will continue reflecting other libraries are not a function etc

Simplistic overview of code (Edited to show that master blade is already requiring jquery once)

--Master Blade--

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}" @if (config('voyager.multilingual.rtl')) dir="rtl" @endif>
    <head>
        <title>@yield('page_title', setting('admin.title') . " - " . setting('admin.description'))</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"/>
    <!-- Google Fonts -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Favicon -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ voyager_asset('images/logo-icon.png') }}" type="image/x-icon">

    <!-- App CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ voyager_asset('css/app.css') }}">

    <!-- fancy tree jquery/css-->
    @yield('css')


    @if(config('voyager.multilingual.rtl'))
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-rtl/3.4.0/css/bootstrap-rtl.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ voyager_asset('css/rtl.css') }}">
    @endif

    <!-- Few Dynamic Styles -->
    <style type="text/css">
        .voyager .side-menu .navbar-header {
            background:#FFFFFF;
            border-color:#FFFFFF;
            {{--background:{{ config('voyager.primary_color','#22A7F0') }};--}}
            {{--border-color:{{ config('voyager.primary_color','#22A7F0') }};--}}
        }
        .widget .btn-primary{
            border-color:{{ config('voyager.primary_color','#22A7F0') }};
        }
        .widget .btn-primary:focus, .widget .btn-primary:hover, .widget .btn-primary:active, .widget .btn-primary.active, .widget .btn-primary:active:focus{
            background:{{ config('voyager.primary_color','#22A7F0') }};
        }
        .voyager .breadcrumb a{
            color:{{ config('voyager.primary_color','#22A7F0') }};
        }
        .app-container .side-menu .panel.widget h5 {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 0px;
            width: 180px;
            text-align: left;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity .3s ease;
            margin-top: 17px;
            left: 68px;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 29px;
        }
        .app-container .side-menu .panel.widget h6 {
            float: left;
            display: block;
            position: absolute;
            top: 15px;
            width: 180px;
            text-align: left;
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity .3s ease;
            margin-top: 17px;
            left: 68px;
            overflow: hidden;
            height: 29px;
        }
        .app-container.expanded .panel.widget h5 {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .app-container.expanded .panel.widget h6 {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .app-container .side-menu:hover .panel.widget h5 {
            opacity: 1;
        }
        .app-container .side-menu:hover .panel.widget h6 {
            opacity: 1;
        }
    </style>

    @if(!empty(config('voyager.additional_css')))<!-- Additional CSS -->
        @foreach(config('voyager.additional_css') as $css)<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset($css) }}">@endforeach
    @endif

    @yield('head')
</head>

<body class="voyager @if(isset($dataType) && isset($dataType->slug)){{ $dataType->slug }}@endif">

<div id="voyager-loader">
    <?php $admin_loader_img = Voyager::setting('admin.loader', ''); ?>
    @if($admin_loader_img == '')
        <img src="{{ voyager_asset('images/logo-icon.png') }}" alt="Voyager Loader">
    @else
        <img src="{{ Voyager::image($admin_loader_img) }}" alt="Voyager Loader">
    @endif
</div>

<?php
if (starts_with(Auth::user()->avatar, 'http://') || starts_with(Auth::user()->avatar, 'https://')) {
    $user_avatar = Auth::user()->avatar;
} else {
    $user_avatar = Voyager::image(Auth::user()->avatar);
}
?>

<div class="app-container">
    <div class="fadetoblack visible-xs"></div>
    <div class="row content-container">
        @include('voyager::dashboard.navbar')
        @include('voyager::dashboard.sidebar')
        <script>
            (function(){
                    var appContainer = document.querySelector('.app-container'),
                        sidebar = appContainer.querySelector('.side-menu'),
                        navbar = appContainer.querySelector('nav.navbar.navbar-top'),
                        loader = document.getElementById('voyager-loader'),
                        hamburgerMenu = document.querySelector('.hamburger'),
                        sidebarTransition = sidebar.style.transition,
                        navbarTransition = navbar.style.transition,
                        containerTransition = appContainer.style.transition;

                    sidebar.style.WebkitTransition = sidebar.style.MozTransition = sidebar.style.transition =
                    appContainer.style.WebkitTransition = appContainer.style.MozTransition = appContainer.style.transition =
                    navbar.style.WebkitTransition = navbar.style.MozTransition = navbar.style.transition = 'none';

                    if (window.localStorage && window.localStorage['voyager.stickySidebar'] == 'true') {
                        appContainer.className += ' expanded no-animation';
                        loader.style.left = (sidebar.clientWidth/2)+'px';
                        hamburgerMenu.className += ' is-active no-animation';
                    }

                   navbar.style.WebkitTransition = navbar.style.MozTransition = navbar.style.transition = navbarTransition;
                   sidebar.style.WebkitTransition = sidebar.style.MozTransition = sidebar.style.transition = sidebarTransition;
                   appContainer.style.WebkitTransition = appContainer.style.MozTransition = appContainer.style.transition = containerTransition;
            })();
        </script>
        <!-- Main Content -->
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="side-body padding-top">
                @yield('page_header')
                <div id="voyager-notifications"></div>
                @yield('content')
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@include('voyager::partials.app-footer')
```

@yield('javascript')

```
<!-- Javascript Libs -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ voyager_asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ voyager_asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> -->


<script>
    @if(Session::has('alerts'))
        let alerts = {!! json_encode(Session::get('alerts')) !!};
        helpers.displayAlerts(alerts, toastr);
    @endif

    @if(Session::has('message'))

    // TODO: change Controllers to use AlertsMessages trait... then remove this
    var alertType = {!! json_encode(Session::get('alert-type', 'info')) !!};
    var alertMessage = {!! json_encode(Session::get('message')) !!};
    var alerter = toastr[alertType];

    if (alerter) {
        alerter(alertMessage);
    } else {
        toastr.error("toastr alert-type " + alertType + " is unknown");
    }

    @endif
</script>


<!-- Javascript Libs -->
<!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ voyager_asset('js/app.js') }}"></script> -->


@if(!empty(config('voyager.additional_js')))<!-- Additional Javascript -->
    @foreach(config('voyager.additional_js') as $js)<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset($js) }}"></script>@endforeach
@endif

</body>
</html>
```

--Fancy Tree Blade --

```
Extends Master Blade
@section('content')
--fancy tree code--
@stop
@section('javascript)
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
        // using default options
        $("#tree").fancytree({
            extensions: ["dnd"],
            checkbox: false,
            icon: false,
            generateIds: true,
            dnd: {
                autoExpandMS: 400,
                focusOnClick: true,
                preventVoidMoves: true, // Prevent dropping nodes 'before self', etc.
                preventRecursiveMoves: true, // Prevent dropping nodes on own descendants
                dragStart: function(node, data) {
                /** This function MUST be defined to enable dragging for the tree.
                 *  Return false to cancel dragging of node.
                 */
                return true;
                },
                dragEnter: function(node, data) {
                /** data.otherNode may be null for non-fancytree droppables.
                 *  Return false to disallow dropping on node. In this case
                 *  dragOver and dragLeave are not called.
                 *  Return 'over', 'before, or 'after' to force a hitMode.
                 *  Return ['before', 'after'] to restrict available hitModes.
                 *  Any other return value will calc the hitMode from the cursor position.
                 */
                // Prevent dropping a parent below another parent (only sort
                // nodes under the same parent)
        /*           if(node.parent !== data.otherNode.parent){
                    return false;
                }
                // Don't allow dropping *over* a node (would create a child)
                return ["before", "after"];
        */
                return true;
                },
                dragDrop: function(node, data) {
                /** This function MUST be defined to enable dropping of items on
                 *  the tree.
                 */
                data.otherNode.moveTo(node, data.hitMode);
                }
            },
}

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/src/jquery-ui-dependencies/jquery.fancytree.ui-deps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/src/jquery.fancytree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/src/jquery.fancytree.dnd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/src/jquery.fancytree.edit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: i tried changing the jquery script to what you suggested however i am still presented with the same error where the perfect scroll bar is not a function.

I honestly have no idea what i am missing/doing wrong. i tried copy pasting the code from the fancy tree DND demo onto a seperate php project which works fine however it just has issues running on this laravel project which i need it for. @Basharmal

Comment: show me the master blade what you have their sometimes if the app.js file is in the above it will show the same error the app.js file should be at the bottom of

Comment: @include('voyager::partials.app-footer')

<!-- Javascript Libs -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ voyager_asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

I do have this set of code in the master file within the body tag BEFORE where the fancy tree content is yielded

Comment: so that's why you are getting the error so take the js/app.js file  after the fancy it will solve the issue

Comment: doing that results in an error where .fancytree isnt recognized as a function.

Comment: In the master file i currently have yield('javascript')
followed by <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ voyager_asset('js/app.js') }}"></script>

Comment: whereas in the section('javascript') 
i have
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="/src/jquery-ui-dependencies/jquery.fancytree.ui-deps.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/src/jquery.fancytree.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/src/jquery.fancytree.edit.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="/src/jquery.fancytree.dnd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: can you post your master.blade

Comment: posted the entire master blade file